# Can I omit 'parameterOrder' attribute in WSDL file?

Tags: .net, wsdl

WSDL snippet:

```
<wsdl:portType name="ITS-ActivityObj">
<wsdl:operation name="addActivity" parameterOrder="pc_SlsmnCode pc_FollowDate pc_ActSrc pc_InXML pl_GetRSXML pc_FieldList pl_WriteXSD pl_MinSchema pc_RSXML pc_batchCount pc_errMsg">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:ITS-Activity_addActivity"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:ITS-Activity_addActivityResponse"/>
  <wsdl:fault name="ITS-ActivityFault" message="tns:FaultDetailMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I'm using .NET env. I seems omit parameterOrder will no affect proxy generation. Client code still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** you can omit it. parameterOrder attribute is defined as an optional attribute [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_parameter).

> Note that this information serves as a
>   "hint" and may safely be ignored by
>   those not concerned with RPC
>   signatures. Also, it is not required
>   to be present, even if the operation
>   is to be used with an RPC-like
>   binding.